# Pandas вхождение подстроки из одной колонки в строку в другой колонке

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Есть такие колонки. Как взять те строки week_num, которые входят во freq, не через apply?

```
 df[df.apply(lambda x: str(x.week_num)[0] in x.freq, axis=1)]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: то, что вы хотите получить на выходе, представьте пожалуйста, формулировка вопроса не совсем понятна.

Comment: понял. вам нужно построчное сравнение обоих столбцов на предмет наличия подстроки.

Comment: а чем вам apply не угодил?

Comment: Долго, кажется есть better practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте с ***numpy***

Для примера создадим рандомный фрейм с двумя строковыми столбцами

```
N = 10000000

s_arr = pd.util.testing.rands_array(10, N)
s_arr2 = pd.util.testing.rands_array(3, N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': s_arr2, 'b': s_arr})
>>> df.head()

     a          b
0   TVE gn2C0WYQ5U
1   3SA 6TBa2w9bTV
2   sC9 uDACJo04ap
3   f4M wZFME4keay
4   J3W 7137gaMft8
```

Проверим по времени работы.

Ваш вариант:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: str(x.a) in x.b, axis=1)]

%%time
Wall time: 4min 52s
```

Другой вариант, очень похожий на Ваш:

```
df[df.apply(lambda x: x[0] in x[1], axis=1)]

%%time
Wall time: 2min 21s
```

Вариант с использованием ***numpy***:

```
v = np.vectorize(lambda x, y: x in y)
df[v(df.a, df.b)]

%%time
Wall time: 2.78 s
```

Выбор очевиден.

P.S. Естественно нужно перевести изначально столбцы в строковый формат.

Comment: Отличный вариант спасибо)